# Use examples to explain why $\sqrt x \cdot \sqrt x=-x$ for all negative values of $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, radicals

I am helping my daughter with this problem in [Saxon Algebra $1$](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/_/6KADAAAACAAJ?hl=en)  (Lesson $69$) and came across this question.

> Use examples to explain why $\sqrt x \cdot \sqrt x=-x$ for all negative values of $x$.

I think when $x$ is negative, $\sqrt x$ is not defined and the question does not make sense. It is possible that I am missing something. Can someone help us please?

Comment: The statement is just plain wrong.  And you are just plain right.

Comment: Question makes sense after imaginary numbers are discussed.

Comment: A common way to interpret $\sqrt{-k^2}$ is as $k\cdot i$ so that for instance if $a=-4$ then $\sqrt{a}=2i.$ However then we have $\sqrt{a} \cdot \sqrt{a}=2i \cdot 2i=-4.$ But this shows $\sqrt{a}\cdot \sqrt{a}=a$ here, rather than the result $-a$ given in your linked picture.

Comment: @herbsteinberg  No it doesn't.

Comment: Almost certainly a typo: it should likely read $\sqrt{-x}\cdot\sqrt{-x} = - x$ for negative $x$. @herbsteinberg: switching to the complex numbers doesn't help.

Comment: @RobArthan's comment is one relatively reasonable interpretation that avoids complications and adheres to typical conventions... :)

Comment: Here you are applying square root for (x)×(x ) and then find the square root of x²  since you need to give a positive answer , you are taking it as - x .   If this approach is valid you can prove that 1  = -1  by considering square root of (-1)×(-1) .

Comment: Perhaps the equation should have been $\sqrt{x^2} = -x$ or all negative values of $x$.

Comment: I agree with **GEdgar's** interpretation -- I think this is what the poser of the problem _wanted_ to ask, then "got clever" and decided to write $ \ \sqrt{x^2} \ $ as a product (which they should have _known better_ than to do).   This issue with radicals still gives some textbook authors trouble (and leads to MSE getting questions about " $ \ \sqrt{-1} · \sqrt{-1} \ =? \neq? \ -1 \ ?? $ " at least once a month).

Answer (score 0):

The textbook's given statement is wrong.

If $x$ is negative, then we can let $x = -a$ for any positive real number $a$. Then

$$\sqrt{x} \cdot \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{-a} \cdot \sqrt{-a} = i\sqrt{a} \cdot i\sqrt{a} = -\sqrt{a}^2 = -a = x.$$

Even with using imaginary numbers, which is a larger field than real numbers, the statement still doesn't make sense.

Comment: The first and last sentences of this answer are correct but the long equation is problematical (some would say wrong). In the complex numbers there is no way to single out $i$ as $\sqrt{-1}$ except by a convention that isn't universally accepted. All you can say is that $-1$ has two square roots, $\pm i$.

Comment: @EthanBolker I'm not sure what you mean when you say I can't single out $i$ as $\sqrt{-1}$ because that's the definition of an imaginary number.

Comment: No that's not the definition of an imaginary number. A  correct definition of a complex number is something like "a number of the form $a+bi$, where $a$ and $b$ are real, $i^2 = -1$ by definition, and the usual rules of arithmetic apply." (See wikipedia.) There is no use of the square root sign in the definition, $-1$ happens to have two square roots. You should  use the square root sign only for nonnegative real numbers. For positive numbers it always stands for the positive root, not to both.

Answer (score 0):

If you substitute  -1 for x you get 1 as -x in the right side but in the left side you have i×i and that gives i² , that is -1 .
Therefore by counterexample method you can prove that the given statement is not valid for negative values of x .
I suggest here the reason is for fractional powers there exists more than one root.